# Order of test while using <runTest>TestClass1</runTest>

Tags: deployment, code-coverage

Does SF run the tests in order in which the tests are specified in
while running tests in a Deployment?

Eg:

```
        <runTest>TestClass1</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass2</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass3</runTest>
```

TestClass1 runs before TestClass2, and so on.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm?search_text=test

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: Same . Curiosity. I was trying for a validation run today , there were interdependent classes and this doubt occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter answer: apparently, yes.

Longer answer: Several casual attempts to get the tests to run out of order did not work, so it appears to be that the tests will run in the order you specify. However, without any formal documentation, there is no way to confirm that this will always be true for all possible configurations, and you should not rely on this behavior for the purposes of avoiding row lock errors or other edge cases in your unit tests.

Edit: If anyone has more definitive proof either way, please feel free to leave a comment or edit this answer.

Comment: AFAIK it goes alphabetically. I was working in a legacy project where test class used to take 2-4 hrs. so we used to do the trick by changing name with a_ to have it first and we can get errors faster.

Comment: in posted question, if you try to see TestClass2 first, I don't think it'll be executed first. However I leave it upto OP

Comment: @YsrShk If you RunLocalTests, it appears to be in either CreatedBy or LastModified order (not sure, I don't modify classes much?), but if you specify RunSpecifiedTests, it appears to be in specified order. Give it a try and see if you can replicate it.

Comment: Will try the a_ approach and RunSpecifiedTests one.