# Apex tests fail in Dev Console Test Suite but pass when run individually

Tags: apex, failing-tests

##### Background

- There is a test utility class

  - Class is marked as `@isTest`
  - There are 5 methods
  - Methods are not marked as `@isTest` because they have parameters
  - All methods are `static`
  - All methods call `ConnectApi` methods
- There are 14 test classes that use this utility class
- I did not write any of this code, so I know no other background and don't have experience running these tests
- *UPDATE:* Acting on the [linked question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-seealldata-true) and the comment from @DerekF, I verified that all the originating test methods which call these utility methods are using `SeeAllData=true`. And I clarified that [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/311356/81648) is correct.

  > Most Connect in Apex methods require access to real organization data, and fail unless used in test methods marked `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)`. [1]

  I do not know whether this has any bearing, but wanted to include the information.

  [1] *https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_TestingApex.htm*

##### Setup

- I want to improve the test utility class: One particular method is a behemoth that creates **lots** of types of test data with dependencies in succession. I want to break that method up into multiple methods that each create one type of data, then this one method (and others in the class) can call them; but also other test classes can have more granular control over certain test data creation.)
- Before I made changes, I wanted to get a "control" by running methods from all 14 test classes that use the utility class, to ensure they pass, so I can verify they still pass during and after I make changes to the utility class.
- I'm not too familiar with Dev Console [Test Suites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_test_suites_creating.htm&type=5), but figured I'd try one out. So I put all 14 aforementioned test classes into one suite to make it easier to run them all whenever I wanted.

##### Issue

- When I ran the Test Suite, individual methods in a small handful of test classes failed.
- They all failed on the same utility method

  ```apex
  public static String createInvoice(String fulfillment_order_id) {
      ConnectApi.FulfillmentOrderInvoiceInputRepresentation input = new ConnectApi.FulfillmentOrderInvoiceInputRepresentation();
      ConnectAPI.FulfillmentOrderInvoiceOutputRepresentation result = ConnectApi.FulfillmentOrder.createInvoice(fulfillment_order_id, input);
      return result.invoiceId;
  }
  ```
- They all failed for the same reason

  > ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Error 1 of 1: ORDER_MANAGEMENT_RECORD_NOT_FOUND - No matching record found. Provide a valid Fulfillment Order ID.
- When I then ran those test classes individually (I did not get as granular as selecting individual test methods to run), without modifying anything anywhere, they passed
- There are other utility class methods for creating an active Order Summary and creating a Fulfillment Order (with an Order Summary `Id` as the parameter). These are being called prior to calling the failing method. But as stated earlier, if I run these tests individually, they pass.

##### Other Notes

- When I run the Test Suite multiple times, there is not a consistent number of methods that fail, and it is not always the same methods/classes that fail.  (Obviously it is only those test methods that call this utility class method, so there is some repeat, but it is not consistently `ClassA` or `methodB()` that fails in every run.)

#### Questions

I guess I don't know enough of the "inner workings" of the Apex code and/or testing processes....

- Can anyone tell me why (or a best guess) these fail in the [Test Suite](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_test_suites_creating.htm&type=5) but not individually?
- Does anyone have suggestions for modifying anything so that I can run these tests in a Test Suite?

---

##### UPDATE (2022.06.24)

###### Workarounds I've tried but which have not worked:

- Adding `(isParallel=false)` at the class level to every class in the test suite
- Adding `(isParallel=false)` at the class level to only the test utility class
- Adding `(isParallel=false)` at the class level to every class in the test suite & the test utility class
- Running this command from my local VS Code terminal...

  `sfdx force:apex:test:run --suitenames "MyTestSuiteName" --synchronous`

  But I discovered this, which is not in the [Run Apex Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_testing.htm) documentation:

  > Synchronous test runs can include test methods from only one Apex class. Omit the --synchronous flag or include tests from only one class
- Running the above command without the `--synchronous` parameter
- Running `sfdx force:apex:test:run --classnames "ClassA,ClassB,...ClassZ"`

###### Workaround I tried that did work:

- Created a PowerShell function that uses current date/time to make a unique file name, then has these lines:

  ```shell
  sfdx force:apex:test:run --synchronous --classnames "ClassA" > $FileName
  sfdx force:apex:test:run --synchronous --classnames "ClassB" >> $FileName
  ...
  sfdx force:apex:test:run --synchronous --classnames "ClassZ" >> $FileName
  ```

---

##### BONUS INFO (2022.06.26)

I (accidentally) discovered that some (at least one) of the `ConnectApi` methods do not require `SeeAllData=true`.

- `ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary()` does NOT
- `ConnectApi.ReturnOrder.createReturnOrder()` does

*If I have time after I get past all of this, I'll* try *to determine the full list (at least as it relates to Sales Order Management).*

Comment: Test Suite as in dev console grouping of tests? If so, the issue is probably not related to test suite vs individual tests, it's something about the assumptions with respect to test data in these tests.

Comment: From [this other question on when to use seeAllData=true](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-seealldata-true), these tests must be using `seeAllData=true`, correct? Not sure if that information will lead anywhere, but it might be a start.

Comment: @identigral : Yes, Dev Console Test Suite. I edited my question to (hopefully) add clarification.

Comment: @DerekF : Good eye. Yes, the originating test methods are using `SeeAllData=true` & then calling these utility methods. According to one of the answers to the question you linked, that appears to be a necessity for tests using `ConnectApi` methods (which I assume is why the test method author(s) are using it). However, off the top of my head, I'm not seeing how that might cause this issue since the tests seem to pass individually & sometimes when run in the suite, but fail other times when run in the suite. I might dig more, though - since I've avoided `SeeAllData` I don't know much about it.

Comment: add `IsTest(isParallel=false)` to the testmethods as the test suite will run the tests in parallel

Comment: @cropredy : Thanks - I didn't know that annotation. However, according to this, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm, `(SeeAllData=true)` and `(isParallel=true)` "annotations cannot be used together on the same Apex method." The actual test methods need `(SeeAllData=true)` [see above], and the utility methods have parameters and thus can't have the `@isTest` annotation. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: tough one ...any chance of non-deterministic SOQL queries?  For example, missing `ORDER BY`? e.g. multiple rows satisfying the query filter and which one appears first is random.

Comment: Clearly use of SeeAllData makes the tests more fragile, since data changes on the org may impact them. Could you isolate the ConnectApi usages so you can mock them out in the tests and avoid the need to see org data?

Comment: @cropredy : I stand corrected. I misread the (confusing) SF documentation a couple of times. *Firstly*, it states what I quoted above: "`@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` and `@isTest(isParallel=true)` annotations cannot be used together on the same Apex method." But you said to set `isParallel` to `false`. So I tried. But I discovered that you cannot put two `xyz=Boolean` annotations - no matter their values - with `@isTest` on a method....

Comment: ... *Secondly*, I glossed over the word **classes** in the first sentence of the doc: "Use the `@isTest(isParallel=true)` annotation to indicate test classes that can run in parallel." (Which to me contradicts the use of the word "method" in that other line.) So I went into all 14 of the test classes in the suite and added `isParallel=false` to the `@isTest` annotation at the class level. Some tests failed on the first run of the suite.

Comment: @PhilW :Since I did not write any of this code, and since the scope of what I was trying to initially do is all in the utility class which the others call and not what the actual test methods are wanting/needing/trying to accomplish, then I am unsure whether anything can be mocked. For my immediate purposes I will just run these tests individually as/after I make changes. But I would like to revisit this as time allows. - I'm not sure if there have ever been any issues on a deployment when all tests are run.

Comment: Deployment always runs tests serially.

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why I did not know or remember that.

Comment: So when you used `sfdx force:apex:test:run`, could you reproduce the ConnectApiException? Do you get the problem when running all tests on this org? If there is any possibility the sequence of test execution has an impact (not sure what Test Suites do), you could [use the migration tool to run tests in different sequences](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340480/order-of-test-while-using-runtesttestclass1-runtest). And BTW, have you done a System.debug on the ID?!

Comment: @FelixvanHove : Yes, when I ran the CLI command (without `--synchronous`) I got the same result: sporadic & inconsistent failures, but on the same utility method with the same error. | RE the migration tool, I did something similar last night - I created a PowerShell function that calls a separate `sfdx force:apex:test:run` on each test class in succession - essentially making it synchronous. That works for my purposes, but I'm still curious about the Test Suites. | I'm not following what you mean by a "System.debug on the ID."

Comment: Regarding System.debug(): As the error is "Provide a valid Fulfillment Order ID." one could double check the ID is not sometimes `null` or `"null"` or of the wrong object type or simply not the one expected.

Comment: BONUS INFO: I just (accidentally) discovered that some of the `ConnectApi` methods do not require `SeeAllData=true`. `ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary()` does not; `ConnectApi.ReturnOrder.createReturnOrder()` does. If I have time after I get past all of this, I'll *try* to determine the full list (at least as it relates to Sales Order Management).